# Alamofire using query parameters status 500

Tags: json, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I'm calling an Api route to get branches of a local store using longitude, latitude & radius. The api route is working just fine on postman. Using Alamofire it is replying internal server error 500. I doubt the issue is in the parameters but i just tested everything and every combination with no success.

Here is my HTTP request:

```
    let branchesRoute = "geo/services/"
//Get branches within location radius
    func getBranchesWithRadius (serviceID: Int, location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (_ status:Bool, _ error:Error?, _ msg:String?, _ branches:NSArray?) ->())
    {

    let route = URL(string:branchIp + branchesRoute + String(serviceID) + "/branches")
    print(route)

    let header: HTTPHeaders = [

        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "auth-token": Helper.shared.getApiKey()//"\(Helper.shared.getApiKey())"
    ]

    let params: Parameters = [
        "longitude" : location.coordinate.longitude,
        "latitude" : location.coordinate.latitude,
        "radius" : Helper.shared.getRadius()
    ]


    print(params)


    Alamofire.request(route!, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success( _):
                let json = response.result.value!
                // let swiftyJson = JSON(json)
                completion(true, nil, nil, json as? NSArray)
                // print(json)

            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
                if response.response?.statusCode == 401 {
                    completion(false,err,"Unauthorized",nil)
                } else {
                    completion(false, err, "Error getting branches",nil)
                }
            }
    }


}
```

This is the route im calling from postman:

> http://100.100.70.185:9090/geo/services/3/branches?longitude=31.331358000000002&latitude=30.082763&radius=1000000

When i used `print()` command in swift these were my results:

`print(params)` = `["longitude": 31.331358000000002, "latitude": 30.082763, "radius": 100000]`

`print(route)` =

```
Optional(http://100.100.70.185:9090/geo/services/3/branches)
```

Regarding the `Optional` i'm just unwrapping it `route!`

Regarding the ip address i wrote here are not the real ones that i use in case you tested and it didn't work out.

Comment: In case of error `response.response.url` is the same as the one in POSTMAN?

Comment: @Larme This is the `response.url Optional(http://100.100.70.185:9090/geo/services/3/branches)`

Comment: It's missing the parameters (response.url.absoluteString)? If you put that address without the params in postman, you have the same 500 error?

Comment: @Larme Yes sure i will have the same error. I tested that. I have doubt that the issue is because of the parameters as i mentioned above but i don't know what is wrong in the code syntax.

Comment: Try `URLEncoding.default` instead of `JSONEncoding.default`?

Comment: @Larme WOOOOOOW IT WORKED..... Please add your answer down there.

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue is in encoding and you have to use the correct `ParameterEncoding` depending on your API implementation.

> Use `URLEncoding` if the `Content-Type` HTTP header field of an encoded request with HTTP body is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`

-

> Use `JSONEncoding` if the `Content-Type` HTTP header field of an
>   encoded request is set to `application/json`

-

> Use `PropertyListEncoding` if the `Content-Type` HTTP header field of
>   an encoded request is set to `application/x-plist`